# ionic popover after dissmiss инициировать метод

Tags: ionic2

у меня есть похожий мокап [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
прямоугольники - ето компании, они могут редактироватся или удалятся (возможно в дальнейшем будет еще несколько действий) и чтобы не плодить в будущем иконок в ряд решили делать через popover.
Cуть в чем.. мы нажимаем кнопку один
(html)

```
<button ion-button icon-only (click)="presentPopover(item)">
    <ion-icon name="more"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

(company.ts)

```
presentPopover(item) {
  let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(PopoverPage, { company: item });
  popover.present();
}
```

и поповер

```
@Component({
    template: `
    <ion-list>
      <ion-list-header>Ionic</ion-list-header>
      <button ion-item (click)="close()">Редактировать</button>
      <button ion-item (click)="close()">удалить</button>
    </ion-list>
  `
})
export class PopoverPage {
    public company: any;
    constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController,public params:NavParams) {
        this.company = params.data.company;
    }
    close() {
        this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Вопрос как я могу вернуть состояние к company.ts и запустить там метод который открывает окно и принимет редактирование?

```
presentEditModal(item){
    this.translate.get(['Name', 'Address', 'Phone', 'Cancel', 'Save', 'Create', 'ukrainian', 'english']).subscribe((translation: string) => {

      let companyEditModal = this.modalCtrl.create(CompanyEdit, {item: item, apiService: this.apiService, translation: translation});

      companyEditModal.onDidDismiss(data => {
        if(data) {
          let newItem = true;
          this.items.forEach((val, i) => {
            if (val.id == data.id) {
              newItem = false;
              return this.items[i] = data;
            }
          });
          if (newItem) {
            this.items.push(data)
          }
        }
      });
      companyEditModal.present()
    });
  }
```

приметка: код `(click)="close()">Редактировать` пока захардкожен для тестов.

**UPD:** я с ним первый день работаю, но думаю может или как то коллбеками разруливается из present && dismiss, или еще как то...  буду рад любым идеям. спасибо

Answer (score 0):

да, коллбек решает ))

```
  popover.onDidDismiss(data => {
      if (data && data.action && data.company) {
          if (data.action == 'edit') {
              this.presentEditModal(data.company);
          }
          if (data.action == 'delete') {
              this.removeCompany(data.company);
          }
      }
  });
```